# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL console

Tags: javascript

Right, sorry stackoverflow community for my last questions and how I acted so i'll try to format my question and anything else necessary;

My main question: What does Unexpected Token Illegal mean and/or how is it triggered? As far as I'm concerned none of my other scripts have triggered it so why now?

Other assumptions from me: Is it just a common syntax error?
Sorry if I've asked too many questions i'm just really curious.

Script: (inserted into google chrome console)

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://www.roblox.com/messages/send",
type: "post",
data: {
    subject: 'Special Private Invitation',
    body:  'Hello,'. \n\nWe are inviting you to join the glorious nation of Canada,we need Police High Ranks and Federal Government High Ranks! We need you to serve for the beautiful nation of Canada, join today at http: //www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=1209061',
    recipientid: userId,
    cacheBuster: new Date().getTime()
},
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('Sent message to ' + username + ' (' + userId + ')');
}
});
if (group > 0) {
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid=" + userId + "&groupid=" + group, function(response) {
    if (response.indexOf('true') == -1) {
        send();
    }
});
} else {
send();
}

function run() {
var timeout = 0;
var elements = document.evaluate('//div[contains(@id,\'ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_GroupMembersUpdatePanel\')]//div[contains(@class,\'GroupMember\')]//span[contains(@class,\'Name\')]/a', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var online = document.evaluate('//div[contains(@id,\'ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_GroupMembersUpdatePanel\')]//div[contains(@class,\'GroupMember\')]//span[contains(@class,\'OnlineStatus\')]/img', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var currentNode = elements.iterateNext();
var currentOnline = online.iterateNext();
while (currentNode) {
    if (currentOnline.src == 'http://www.roblox.com/images/online.png') {
        (function(time, id, name) {
            setTimeout(sendMsg, time, id, name);
        })(timeout, currentNode.href.match(/\d+/)[0], currentNode.textContent);
        timeout += waitTime * 1000;
    }
    currentNode = elements.iterateNext();
    currentOnline = online.iterateNext();
}
__doPostBack('ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane$dlUsers_Footer$ctl02$ctl00', '');
var ready = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('__EVENTTARGET').value == "") {
        clearInterval(ready);
        setTimeout(run, timeout);
    }
}, 10);
}
var ready = setInterval(function() {
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    clearInterval(ready);
    run();
}
}, 10);
```

Comment: In where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
body:  'Hello,'. \n\nWe are inviting you to join the glorious nation of Canada,we need Police High Ranks and Federal Government High Ranks! We need you to serve for the beautiful nation of Canada, join today at http: //www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=1209061',
```

You could show us how its being generated. Anyway, it should be something like:

```
body:  'Hello,\'. \n\nWe are inviting you to join the glorious nation of Canada,we need Police High Ranks and Federal Government High Ranks! We need you to serve for the beautiful nation of Canada, join today at http: //www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=1209061',
```

It seems that the string `'.` is inserted in your message, which breaks it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but 'Uncaught ReferenceError: userId is not defined' surprisingly comes up. I never knew coding would be this hard and irritating -Yarg

Comment: @Yarg This error is probably being caused by this code `recipientid: userId,` you should check the variable `userId`. Why don't you post your entire code?

Answer (score 0):

"Unexpected Token Illegal" means that you have something wrong with your syntax. As a starting point, this line is invalid:

```
    body:  'Hello,'. \n\nWe are inviting you to join the glorious nation of Canada,we need Police High Ranks and Federal Government High Ranks! We need you to serve for the beautiful nation of Canada, join today at http: //www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=1209061',
```

The second `'` terminates the string literal, then you have `.\n\n`, followed by more literal text. That's not valid syntax, and the parser can't tell what to do with it. You need to make a valid string, like this:

```
    body:  "Hello,\n\nWe are inviting you to join the glorious nation of Canada,we need Police High Ranks and Federal Government High Ranks! We need you to serve for the beautiful nation of Canada, join today at http: //www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=1209061",
```

There may be other errors, as well, but this one stood out.